# How do I add spaces between regexp groups in hive?

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to space out camel case strings in a specific way in hive. Any adjacent capital letters stay as a block unless one of them leads into other alphanumeric characters, in which case the capital letter is in a block with the following alphanumeric string.

For example, `HELLOWorld` should become `HELLO World`. `HelloWorld5` should become `Hello World5`. `HELLOWorldPeople` should become `HELLO World People`. Sometimes the entire string is lowercase. Every string is followed by `STRING` so it would be `HelloWorldSTRING`, but the last part should be discarded.

This is the regex I have written that I think works in splitting the words into groups correctly, but I could be wrong:

```
([A-Z]?[a-z0-9]+)+STRING|([A-Z]*)([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*STRING
```

Is there any way to insert a space between every group in hive? regexp_replace does not seem suitable for this problem, as far as I've been able to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace every capital letter preceded/followed by something else other than a capital letter, with a space and itself.

```
hive> select regexp_replace('ThisIsHELLOWorldPeople','(?<=[^A-Z])[A-Z]|[A-Z](?=[^A-Z])',' $0');
OK
 This Is HELLO World People
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually simpler than I thought. I needed to select the spaces between the words, not the words themselves.

```
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(string_col, "(.*)STRING"), 
           "(?<=[A-Za-z])()(?=([A-Z][a-z]))", 
           " ")
```

Comment: Same here. Need to be tested against the OP examples.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz This is the answer of the OP ;)